# W3C Markup Validation HTML5 TextArea

Tags: php, forms, w3c-validation

I am having trouble validating this form in HTML5. I am down to my final error, and am coming up with nothing!!! Hope someone can help!

**The section of the form that is causing the error**

```
<textarea name="content" value="<?=$content;?>" class="rounded" <?php echo $_POST['content'] ? $_POST['content'] : "" ?> required="required"></textarea>
```

**This is the error that the W3C Validator is pulling up!**

```
Error Line 177, Column 78: Attribute value not allowed on element textarea at this point.

…xtarea name="content" value="" class="rounded" required="required"></textarea>
```

The error is on the closing **>** after the required="required"

Again hopefully someone can help!! :)

**- ANSWER FOUND -**

OK! for anyone who may need the answer to the above question...

The textarea should read, to pass W3C validation

```
<textarea name="content" class="rounded" <?php echo $_POST['content'] ? $_POST['content'] : "" ?> required="required"><?=$content;?></textarea>
```

This will still allow the form to stay populated after submit..

Comment: because you put the "value" of textarea field between opening and closing tag : `<textarea> :: HERE :: </textarea>`.

Comment: `"Attribute value not allowed on element textarea at this point."`  I think that pretty much sums up the error... All the information you need is in that message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `value` attribute for `<textarea>`. Put your content inside the `<textarea>` container.

Sample:

```
<textarea name="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.
</textarea>
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: in texarea tags the value is <textarea>Value</textarea>

Comment: No idea why people downvoted this... This is the correct answer.  You need to put your textual content **within** the `textarea` tag.

Comment: Quick! get rid of that [W3fools](http://w3fools.com/) link! :P  Better use this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea.  As it stands, your answer is correct **except** for the link to w3fools...  Remove/replace that and you have yourself a great answer :P

Comment: @Lix: And Mozilla is a more independent resource? ;-)

Comment: w3school is notorious for providing out of date and sometimes simply incorrect information.  `"W3Schools.com is not affiliated with the W3C in any way. Members of the W3C have asked W3Schools to explicitly disavow any connection in the past, and they have refused to do so."`

Comment: @Lix: Good to know. I usually use the W3C definitions, but they are not always suitable for every audience...

Comment: That's fine - but be aware than any self respecting web developer will cringe at the site of a link to w3schools...  It's an accident waiting to happen :P

Comment: thanks your answer did help!! It would be good for people who are looking for answers to get a complete answer though!! :)